# Nightwatch - How can I CSS select a nested button with no unique identifiers on the button itself

Tags: javascript, html, css, nightwatch.js

In image 'UI' I need to select the second 'Setup' button on the page.

I've tried many different combinations of trying to select this element but have had no luck. I've seen some related posts but most talk about having 1 parent and 1 or 2 child elements. In this case I need to go along this path: li[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCCyO.png)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCCyO.png)/div/a. I'm just unsure of how to string that together.

Xpath is not an option unfortunately as the id changes from session to session.

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph0wF.png)

[Inspecting the DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCCyO.png)

For additional context, the other options in the ul (Google Auth & Voice Auth) are identical to the SMS li.

Ideally, I would want to do something like this, but I feel that I am way off:

```
selector: 'li[data-se$="SMS"] + a[class$="button link-button"]'
```

Comment: Take out the + which indicates a direct relation whereas you are trying to get that anchor element which is somewhat down inside the li.

Comment: I figured that was the wrong syntax, I'm trying to figure out the correct operator to drill that far down into the li. Or if it's even possible.

Comment: Just take out that +. You don’t need to specify every single layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to select the button with use of the descendant combinator.

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#descendant-combinators

```
selector: 'li[data-se="SMS"] * a[data-se$="button"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not select by the data attribute?

If you need to "click" on the button, you'll need to decide when that happens.  You could for example do it on page load:

```js
const sms = document.querySelector("[data-se='SMS']");
const simulated_button_click = sms.getElementsByClassName('link-button')[0];
```

```html
<body onload="simulated_button_click.click()">
...
<div class="enroll-factor-list">
    <ul class="list-content">
        <li data-se="GOOGLE_AUTH" class="enroll-factor-row clearfix">
            <div class="enroll-factor-icon-container">
                <div class="enroll-factor-button">
                    <a class="button link-button" href="#">Setup</a>
                </div>
            </div>
      </li>
      <li data-se="SMS" class="enroll-factor-row clearfix">
            <div class="enroll-factor-icon-container">
                <div class="enroll-factor-button">
                    <a class="button link-button" href="#">Setup</a>
                </div>
            </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
...
</body>
```

Comment: I need to be able to click() on the button itself.  Just using "[data-se='SMS']" will select the whole area. I didn't mention needing to click the button itself in my post, my apologies.

Comment: I was able to find what I needed with use of the descendant combinator. But I think your solution is good and would work if Nightwatch JS wasn't involved.